# How to Track Visitors Coming from Adwords

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-ads-api

There is a lead form on my website where we track from which source visitors have arrived. I wanted to disable the drop down and auto populate it with predefined data if the visitor is from adwords. This form is not on the landing page. Is there a way I could do that by reading cookie or any other way.

Answer (score 0):

You could tag your destination url's with Google's URL builder and then render what ever you want according to the params you get from the url

http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1033867&rd=1

Answer (score -1):

You should be using [Google Analytics.](http://www.google.com/analytics/)

[image]

Comment: I think you have not read the question completely. I wanted to disable a form element if the user is coming from adwords. Now I am not sure how using Google analytics is going to help this.

Comment: sorry I think I just gave an answer seeing your question title. what is your backend language you need to do this using php or perl

Comment: Backend language on my website is PHP